# Is it possible to add wordpress plugin in a page-template?

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages, custom-theme

I have created a theme using a Bootstrap template.Now I want add a `wordpress` plugin in the created theme. I have tried to add a plugin in the theme the plugin is installed in WordPress but it is not making any changes to the webpage?

Is there any query has to be included in functions.php file?

Comment: You can switch your theme to TweentySixteen to check the plugin functionality. If it work with wp default theme then there is problem in your theme. For adding the plugin in your function, you can include the main plugin file in your functions.php

Comment: Is there any example for how add plugin file in functions.php

Answer (score 0):

Copy plugin file to your theme directory then include its main file. If your plugin folder name is `custom-plugin` and main file of that plugin is `custom-plugin.php` then include that in your functions.php like that

```
include_once( get_stylesheet_directory().'/custom-plugin/custom-plugin.php');
```